# Find if current user's public SSH key is authorized for SSH on remote host using PHP or Bash

Tags: php, bash, ssh

I need a PHP script to execute a script on a remote system.

It's working great where the current user is authorized on the remote system.

However, before running the script, I want to check if the public key on the local system is authorized in the `authorized_keys` file on the remote system.

Is there a way to do this? I tried executing something like this:

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o BatchMode=yes -o ChallengeResponseAuthentication=no host.address.com 2>&1 | grep "Permission denied"
```

but it just hangs the console when authentication is successful.

Comment: You need to execute some command on the remote host.  What is happening is that you are successfully logging into the remote host and it is waiting for your input.  Try adding `exit` after `host.address.com`.

Comment: Brilliant, that works great! I was almost there. haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command like this and grab the exit code:

```
ssh -q host exit
```

This will contact host `host` and execute command `exit`. Return code 0 mean everything is fine

If you want to grab exit code execute after `ssh`

```
EXIT_CODE=$?
```

and then check the variable

Comment: The `-q` parameter didn't work for some reason, but adding `exit` after the host name in the command I included in the question works great. Thanks.

Comment: @Skeets, in some versions of openssh `-q` suppress banner messages. If it does't work and you do not need those messages you can redirect them to `/dev/null` :)

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I thought it was "return quit code" or something. I'm not getting an exit code though. But I'm getting enough to make it work. :)